# WooCommerce loads wrong path to assets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WP site with WC, which was working fine to my knowledge. I recently noticed a lot of the functions weren't working in WooCommerce (i.e. inquiry functions, show/hide boxes etc).

I have nailed it down to this:

The files need to be loaded from the correct path.  Seems like WC is appending the url twice in the path.

CORRECT PATH TO FILE:

http://my-web-site.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js

WHAT IS BEING CALLED:

http://my-web-site.com/my-web-site.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js

I nailed down the source file, but I couldn't find anything that would cause this path to differ from other calls.  I am sure i am missing something. Here is the code:

```
    public function load_scripts() {
    global $post, $wp;

    $suffix               = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    $lightbox_en          = get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_lightbox' ) == 'yes' ? true : false;
    $ajax_cart_en         = get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart' ) == 'yes' ? true : false;
    $assets_path          = str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', WC()->plugin_url() ) . '/assets/';
    $frontend_script_path = $assets_path . 'js/frontend/';

    // Register any scripts for later use, or used as dependencies
    wp_register_script( 'chosen', $assets_path . 'js/chosen/chosen.jquery' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-blockui', $assets_path . 'js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.60', true );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-payment', $assets_path . 'js/jquery-payment/jquery.payment' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.2', true );
    wp_register_script( 'wc-credit-card-form', $assets_path . 'js/frontend/credit-card-form' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-payment' ), WC_VERSION, true );

    wp_register_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation', $frontend_script_path . 'add-to-cart-variation' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), WC_VERSION, true );
    wp_register_script( 'wc-single-product', $frontend_script_path . 'single-product' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), WC_VERSION, true );
    wp_register_script( 'wc-country-select', $frontend_script_path . 'country-select' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), WC_VERSION, true );
    wp_register_script( 'wc-address-i18n', $frontend_script_path . 'address-i18n' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), WC_VERSION, true );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-cookie', $assets_path . 'js/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.3.1', true );
```

Comment: try changing   `$frontend_script_path = $assets_path .js/frontend/';` to     `$frontend_script_path = $assets_path;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  made the change, but it did not fix it, still same path loads.

Comment: as a temporary fix, i hard-coded the path values, but obviously this is only until a better solution is found.

Comment: Any additional feedback here? I'm having this problem as well once I upgraded WooCommerce to 2.2 (might have occurred before that version because I upgraded from 2.0.20) and it wasn't occurring prior to upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and it seemed to be caused by the `Root Relative URLs` plugin. Disabling this problematic plugin (it seems to adversely effect `WP Mail` as well) seemed to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using CONSTANTS when defining paths. At least then they cannot be overwritten.

e.g.

```
define('AD_PATH', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

And you can use it then whereever:

```
wp_register_script( 'chosen', AD_PATH . '/assets/js/chosen/chosen.jquery' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
```